# login through database(mssql) in android

Tags: android

i am making a login page in android. so i want to verify the user and it should be  done through

database(MSSQL) and then proceed forward. so can any1 tell how to go forward.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have a local MSSQL database on android devices, the preferred database ist SQLite.

However, if the android device has internet access, then you could access an external MSSQL database by either webservice calls or the jtds library.

Answer (score 0):

First of all android has SQLLITE database not mssql.
If i am right you just want to create some login page where you just need to save login name and password in database. Its very simple and you will find ample number of examples for that.

Here is a simple tutorial for that http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842 .
And you will find many more.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing databases directly from Android is not preferred for several reasons: [Why is the paradigm of "Direct Database Connection" not welcomed by Android Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826242/why-is-the-paradigm-of-direct-database-connection-not-welcomed-by-android-platf/4826718#4826718)